# Align table using rowspan and colspan

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to create a table using `rowspan` and `colspan` and it is almost done. only the issue is in last `tr`. I don't know why but it is not picking the `rowspan` in last tr.

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;    
}
```

```html
<table style="width:50%">
 <tr>
  <td height="75px">1</td>
  <td colspan="4" height="75px">2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="3" colspan="2">a</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
 </tr>
 
</table>
```

As you can see in result I want to merge the last blank td with **a**.

This is the result I want:

[image]

Comment: Do you still want the cell with "2" in the first row to overlap the "a" cell?

Comment: i want the same result as above except i want to just merge the last blank tds with a like 1 and 2 is exactly i want i just want to span a with last two blank tds and remain will be same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the first set of cells with 3, 4, 5 after the td with the row+colspan.

And omit the empty cells from the last row.

Result:

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:50%">
  <tr>
    <td width="20%" height="75px">1</td>
    <td colspan="4" height="75px">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3" colspan="2">a</td>
    <td width="20%">3</td>
    <td width="20%">4</td>
    <td width="20%">5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note that the second column never has content of its own, it is always part of a colspan set. That would normally make the second column collapse on most if not all browsers, and that is why the cell width is being set.

Comment: This is not the result i want

Comment: i want the same result as above except i want to just merge the last blank tds with a like 1 and 2 is exactly i want i just want to span a with last two blank tds and remain will be same

Comment: See my update. By giving the 4 columns that have content a width of 20%, the remaing column (the always empty one) gets what is left so also 20%. You can of course change the percentages as needed.

Comment: Yup thanks a lot, i forget to give width thanks alot

Comment: can we do this without giving width or not?

Comment: Something needs to set width for the empty column, or else it collapses. You can do this with html attributes (as above), and it is quite possible that it can also be done with css definitions. Some co-answerers have done it with cells that were made invisible, which even then still contribute to the table layout.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply an error in counting. `rowspan="3"` means it spans **three** rows.

First row

```
<tr>
    <td rowspan="3" colspan="2">a</td>
</tr>
```

Second row

```
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>
```

Third row

```
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>
```

Fourth row … so it doesn't span it.

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>
```

(You should omit the empty cells from the final row too).

Comment: First row is <tr>
  <td height="75px">1</td>
  <td colspan="4" height="75px">2</td>
 </tr>

Comment: @jayantrawat — That's the first row in the whole table, not the first row in the set of rows being spanned.

Comment: This is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aomkLj02/) can you please do this for me

Comment: i tried that too what you are saying but not working

Comment: i have updated my question. This is the result i want

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;    
}
```

```html
<table style="width:50%">
 <tr>
  <td height="75px">1</td>
  <td colspan="4" height="75px">2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="3" colspan="2">a</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>      
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>      
 <tr style="visibility:hidden">      
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
 </tr>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not @peterB did what i want

Comment: this is also giving the same result. but ofcourse his solution  is more reliable.

Comment: Yes that was exactly i want. By the way thanks for your time too

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep the overlapping of the cells as you stated, you need to use an "invisible" row for reference. I'm not aware of any other way to achieve this, as colspan and rowspan need actual cells as a reference.

Here's an updated version of your example that works that way. Had to change the CSS a bit as well to prevent double borders around the hidden cells.

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;    
}

.reference,
.reference td {
  padding: 0px 5px;
  height: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
  border: 0 none;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:50%">
 <tr>
  <td height="75px">1</td>
  <td colspan="4" height="75px">2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="4" colspan="2">a</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="reference">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 
</table>
```