# HTML table with mixed rowspan

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to use HTML to construct a table with three rows (1-3) and three columns (A-C) forming nine "virtual cells" (A1, B1, C1, A2, B2, C2, A3, B3, C3) and apply row spanning so that:

- cell A1 span all three rows (covering A2 and A3)
- cell C1 span two rows (covering C2)
- cell B2 span two rows (covering B3)

This is what I want to see:

[image: Expected]

This is the HTML I thought would give me that:

```html
<html>
  <head>
 <style>
 table { border-collapse: collapse; }
 td { border: 1px solid black; padding: 1em; vertical-align: top; }
 </style>
  </head>
  <body>
 <table>
   <tr><td rowspan="3">A1</td><td>B1</td><td rowspan="2">C1</td></tr>
   <tr><td rowspan="2">B2</td></tr>
   <tr><td>C3</td></tr>
 </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

But that gives me:

[image: Actual]

What is the correct way to get what I want? Or is it not possible?

This is for use in technical documentation. It is not a layout issue, the content is semantically a table.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42087795/align-table-using-rowspan-and-colspan# - just with rowspan instead of colspan.

Comment: @Connum it's not a doublicate of that ...

Comment: It is, just for another table layout. I have postet the exact same solution, just adapted to your layout, as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to prevent the rows collapsing without the need for additional markup, you can attach a phantom cell to each row with `tr::after` set to `display: table-cell` with your cell padding on top and bottom and a unicode blank space:

```
tr::after {
  content: '\00a0';
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 1em 0;
}
```

Gives you the correct result:

[image: Example]

It's worth noting that the phantom cell will create a slight gap to the right like this:

[image: Gap example]

#### Full snippet

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
  vertical-align: top;
}

tr:after {
  content: '\00a0';
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">A1</td>
    <td>B1</td>
    <td rowspan="2">C1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">B2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could hack it like this:

```html
<html>
  <head>
 <style>
 table { border-collapse: collapse; }
 td { border: 1px solid black; padding: 1em; vertical-align: top; }
 </style>
  </head>
  <body>
 <table>
   <tr>
      <td style="width:0px;padding:0;border:0"></td>
      <td rowspan="3">A1</td>
      <td>B1</td>
      <td rowspan="2">C1</td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
      <td style="width:0px;padding:0;border:0;height:50px"></td>
      <td rowspan="2">B2</td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
     <td style="width:0px;padding:0;border:0"></td>
      <td>C3</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

... but I would recommend to use another structure instead of tables, since it doesn't have a lot in common with table, besides the columns.

Comment: I need to use tables. This is for technical documentaiton, not just for layout.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution without having to know the table height up front, using hidden table cells, like in [Align table using rowspan and colspan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42087795/align-table-using-rowspan-and-colspan#) (as I said, it's basically a duplicate, just another layout):

```html
<html>
  <head>
 <style>
 table { border-collapse: collapse; }
 td { border: 1px solid black; padding: 1em; vertical-align: top; }
  td.hidden { visibility: hidden; padding: 1em 0; border: 0 none; }
 </style>
  </head>
  <body>
 <table>
   <tr><td rowspan="3">A1</td><td>B1</td><td rowspan="2">C1</td><td class="hidden">&zwnj;</td></tr>
   <tr><td rowspan="2">B2</td><td class="hidden">&zwnj;</td></tr>
   <tr><td>C3</td><td class="hidden">&zwnj;</td></tr>
 </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Must I really add hidden cells to get this working? This is a requirement for technical documentation, not just for layout. It sure is ackward for a technical writer to add hidden cells.

Comment: there are a couple of other answers with other approaches already, you can choose which one fits you best - having to know the table height or using hidden cells. There's sadly no other way for HTML tables to span in the way you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for that confirmation. Very good to know. And **very** surprising to me. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Why not just setting a `height` to the `tr` cause it is a table the height will adjust anyways if there is more content inside the row.

something like so:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
  height: 30px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">A1</td>
    <td>B1</td>
    <td rowspan="2">C1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">B2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I cannot set an explicit height since that would break layout when a cell contains more text.

Comment: @MårtenWikström not sure what you mean. Do you want it to be overflow hidden? Did you try it? For me this works good, see here: https://jsfiddle.net/nfn898o6/

Answer (score 1):

Otherwise,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      table { border-collapse: collapse; }
      td{border: 1px solid black; padding: 1em; vertical-align: top; }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
     <tr>
       <td rowspan="3">A1</td>
       <td>B1</td>
       <td rowspan="2">C1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td rowspan="2">B2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td rowspan="2">C3</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But then it is not clear that C1 span over the second row completely.

Comment: @MårtenWikström its not only I guess. Look at the adjust made in the height. The whole table has been adjusted. Notice that the height is not 3 units its 2.5 units.
I wrote this without the use of explicit height property.

Answer (score 0):

It's depend the height of your table.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBOgpx

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">A1</td>
    <td>B1</td>
    <td rowspan="2">C1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" style="height:65px">B2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Setting an explicit height is not an option for me.